# Adding Crystal Report in Vb.net in Setup Project using assembly

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a setup project and I want to add a Crystal Report on it, but I don't know what to select.

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
```

[image: Screenshot]

I want it to work on other machines as well. Do I have to select all the `CrystalDecisions` lines, or are there specific ones to select?

I am using CrystalReports 13_0_10

Comment: you just want to add report file in assembly or want to include a crystal report setup inside a MSI ?

Comment: @hdkhardik yes i want to add the CR inside the MSI.